# Why am I seeing concurrentUpdateException during login?

Tags: atg

Ours is a large ecommerce application built on ATG. On many sessions I'm seeing ConcurrentUpdateException during login itself, even if there was no other activity by the user recently. This is resulting in other exceptions while doing other activities.

Answer (score 0):

Please do Check your transaction properly.
Following are the Best practice steps to update **ATG** Order

When you update the order Please follow the below steps.

1. Acquire transaction level lock.
2. Begin a transaction.
   3- Synchronize the order.
3. Make changes to order.
4. Update order.
5. End synchronization.
6. End transaction.
7. Release lock.

Note: Avoid update order in commerce pipeline chains. It might lead to nested transaction.

Even Check any modifications on Order Manager component with mergeOrders method.